# view spec fails with "Query does not return ResultSet"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

Just trying to do a simple view spec. When I first create this spec and run it, it worked great. But later on when I needed to create the model class (app/models/request.rb) it starts failing with the following error:

> Failure/Error: render
>        ActionView::Template::Error:
>          query does not return ResultSet

Here is my view spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "requests/new.html.erb" do   

  it "renders a form to reate a request" do  
    assign(:request, mock_model("Request"))  
    render
    rendered.should have_selector("form",
      :method => "post",
      :action => requests_path
    ) do |form|
      form.should have_selector("input",:type=>"submit")
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the view:

```
<%= form_for @request do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

I can't seem to track down what is wrong and Google offers no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears it was a problem that there was no active migration for the model. Beginner mistake.