# How to test database views using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, rspec, factory-bot

I have a class that is based on the view in database. How do I write Rspec tests for the view? I am using FactoryGirl to create test data for base models, then I call the controller action to do some processing on that data. But when I write controller and model specs to verify the view data, then I get JDBC error :

ActiveRecord::JDBCError: query does not return ResultSet: PRAGMA table_info("transaction_history_view")

How do I write specs to test the rest apis that return the results from queries based on database view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [view spec fails with "Query does not return ResultSet"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836014/view-spec-fails-with-query-does-not-return-resultset)

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could add the code that you do have for more context.

Comment: please add some code to your question